# breakpoint does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Everything was fine with my code, and in case that I had an issue, I was able to do tracing by using breakpoints. However, something happened and I am not able to use the breakpoints anymore. The code goes to the end and do not stop where it should stop with the breakpoints. This is with c# and visual studio 2015. Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: What does it say if you hover over the breakpoint with your mouse?

Comment: Are the breakpoints red outlined with no fill?

Comment: Check if you are running your application in Release mode

Comment: Make sure you are not running a release build by accident.

Comment: You've likely chosen the wrong application type. When you start up are you selecting native or managed code?

Comment: @mason it says "Location:MainWindow.xaml.cs" following with the line number and the other details.

Comment: @NicholasV. No it is with red fill

Comment: @PraveenPaulose It is with Debug mode

Comment: @InBetween it is in Debug mode

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try clearing your symbol cache. You can do this in Visual Studio by selecting Tools - Options - Debugging - Symbols.

Select 'Empty Symbol Cache' and click 'OK.'

Close VS and reopen.

Under 'Build', go ahead and completely rebuild your solution and then try to debug again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've followed your instruction, but unfortunately it didn't work. I really don't know what to do!

Comment: Can you debug other apps without this problem, or is it limited to just this one? You can try deleting all of the files in the bin\debug folder and starting debug again. It will recreate all of these files when the compile kicks off for the debug. If that doesn't work, I'll have to let someone else suggest a fix.

Comment: I have Win7, so I deleted all the files in the Users\AppData\Local\Temp folder. Is it the same with bin\debug? where can I fined the bin\debug folder? I am so thankful for your help

Comment: I found the  bin\debug folder and deleted all its contains, it is also didn't work